# Java bluetooth program not working

Tags: java, bluetooth, arduino

I'm using this program to send some data from Java to Arduino:

JAVA

```
public class Arduino extends PApplet{

public void connect(){
String[] serials = Serial.list();
Serial port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
port.write('H');
port.dispose();
}
```

ARDUINO

```
 void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
 Serial.println("Start");
}

void loop() {
if(Serial.available()){
int a = Serial.read();
Serial.print(a);
 }
}
```

The problem is that every time I send data, I lose the bluetooth connection. Can someone explain what's wrong with it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> *every time I send data, I lose the bluetooth connection.*

for sure, you are calling the dispose method after sending the char, then is the connection gone.... try removing the dispose method instead..

```
public void connect(){
    String[] serials = Serial.list();
    Serial port = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[0], 9600);
    port.write('H');
    //port.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be sending a `'H'` on connecting. Great. Right after that you call [`dispose()`](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn-history/r7788/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/everything/processing/serial/Serial.html#dispose%28%29). Quoting docs for `dispose()`,

> Used by PApplet to shut things down.

Firstly, you don't need to do that. You do something like that when you want to disconnect.

Secondly, that is a horrible way of disconnecting. You should call [`stop()`](http://processing.googlecode.com/svn-history/r7788/trunk/processing/build/javadoc/everything/processing/serial/Serial.html#stop%28%29) instead. Quoting docs for `stop()`,

> Stop talking to serial and shut things down.
>
> Basically just a user-accessible version of dispose(). For now, it just calls dispose(), but dispose shouldn't be called from applets, because in some libraries, dispose() blows shit up if it's called by a user who doesn't know what they're doing.